# How to use . operator in python dict like object in Node?

Tags: python, typescript

I have a dict in python like this:

```
person={'name':'felix','sex':'m','age':12}
```

when I want to access 'name' property, I have to call like this:
`person['name']`, that means I have to type the full letter `name` in my editor instead of only type the start letter `n` to wait the editor auto-input the others, but if it's Node(with typescript), if will be like when I type `person.na`,the editor will auto-input the `name` letter, this will make it more easier and make less mistakes.
Is there a lib or some other methods to do the same like in python?

Comment: you are looking for `class`es, you can access their attributes this way

Comment: You can use a [named tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) instead.

Comment: So.... is your question about python or auto-complete functionality of an IDE? I'm confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with dictionaries in python.
You could use something like a [named tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).

Comment: This is purely an IDE feature. Since attributes of an object can be added or removed at any time, just like a `dict`, the IDE could do exactly the same thing for `dict`s as it does for objects. The fact that it doesn't work is because the IDE vendors chose not to implement it, not because it "is not possible".